# Telerik Error Issue / Xaml ParseException MeasureOverride

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik, expression-blend

```
XamlParseException: [Line: 0 Position: 0]
StackTrace
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight) 
InnerException: None
```

I've ran into this before and would normally ctrl+Z and just skip back because its a syntax typo or something simple but then I'll come into this and I'm without a design view in Expression Blend. If I comment out all the telerik controls being used the design view loads again fine and the error goes away. Can someone point me in the direction to remedy this? Thanks for looking either way![image]

P.S. - The app still seems to build fine, just no design view with these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Borislav! The project was silverlight but there was no Silverlight 5 involved unfortunately. The problem was resolved after updating the telerik controls and now I have ran into it again. If I comment out all of the telerik controls it loads the design view in Blend again. I'd really like to know if anyone else has ran into this before?

Normally when I see this I look for an inane syntax error but there are none and the telerik controls are their defaults. Any insight would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question whether you are using Silverlight or WPF, but in case you are using Silverlight:
There are some [known issues](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/708140/silverlight-forum-mefedmvvm-design-time-feature-doesnt-work-in-silverlight-5) with the Visual Studio designer when Silverlight 5 is installed. The workaround is to install VS11 developer preview (which itself installs .NET 4.5) or uninstall Silverlight 5.